# django app module and relative import

Tags: django

Hey I want to use some python module in my app. The problem is that this module has to be "hosted" inside app folder. So I put module in myapp/packagaes folder (myapp/packages/modulename) and then I try to load it in django app `from myapp.packages import modulename` - this work fine until module consists from submodules which import some other submodules from this module - then the import path is wrong because there isn't `myapp.` prfix before import path.

For example:

```
myapp/packages/module/submodule1/...
myapp/packages/module/submodule2/...
```

and in `myapp/packages/module/submodule1/__init__.py`:

```
import module.submodule2 # this will fail because it should be import myapp.module.submodule2
```

So how I can overcome this situation without modifying module source?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a bit more detail: the failure message and all the import statements involved would be helpful.  (and maybe give another pass at the sentences you use and see if you can explain your problem more clearly).